# Give orders to app from Google Assistant using Dialogflow

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I'm wondering if it's possible. What I want is 
talking to google assistant ("Ok google" style), so that I can make react an Android app.
This far (using Dialogflow chat tutorial as a basis) I've been able to ask something from the app, making Dialogflow respond, catch the answer and then update my app.

But I don't want :

APP <------> DIALOGFLOW

I want :

GOOGLE ASSISTANT ----> DIALOGFLOW ----> APP .

Is it possible ?

**EDIT** 
Generic example of client app :

For now I can type "Tell me a joke" on my app, and I get a joke from Google Assistant, and I can display it on my app.

But what I want is saying "Ok Google, tell me a joke", and instead of Google Assistant responding me directly, I want it to send the response to my app (in order to display it). My problem here is that the request "tell me a joke" is made outside of the app, so how to make the app receive the response ?

This is, with a quick and simple example, what I want to do :)

Can the response be broadcasted to several clients in anyway?

Comment: Can you update your question with wireframes for the desired user interfaces? I'm a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've edited my question with a little example/scenario of what i want to achieve.